# одноразвый if внутри цикла на fortran

Tags: if, fortran

не могу решить задачу. задача выглядит так:

> Дано целое число K и набор ненулевых целых чисел; признак его завершения — число 0. Вывести номер первого числа в наборе, большего K. Если таких чисел нет, то вывести 0.

я смог вывести не первую, а последнюю цифру, соответствующую условию, вот так:

```
program series16
implicit none
integer::k,x,a=1,i=0
print*,'enter K:'
read*,k
print*,'enter a number:'
read*,x
do while (x>0 .or. x<0)
  print*,'enter a number:'
  read*,x
  i=i+1
  if (x>k) then
    a=a+i
  else
    a=0
  end if
end do
print*,'the order of last number greater than K:',a
end program series16
```

как можно остановить if при первом же выполнении его условия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    a=0
    do while (x>0 .or. x<0)
      print*,'enter a number:'
      read*,x
      i=i+1
      if (x>k .and. a.eq.0) then
        a = i
      end if
    end do
    print*,'index of first number greater than K:',a
```

Comment: сам цикл не должен заканчиваться